# Eval expr that generate XML file

Tags: xml, eval

For a side project, i want to write an eval expr (just boolean for now) wich generate XML file.

For example:

$./myBinary "TRUE AND (FALSE OR TRUE)" > foo.out

$cat foo.out

```
<AND>
  <TRUE>
  <OR>
    <TRUE>
    <FALSE>
  </OR>
</AND>
```

I have no idea where to start.

Which langage will be the most easy to use to code this ? (performances are not an issue).

Maybe something like that had already been made but i crawled the internet with no answers.

Comment: Actually you want to do infix to prefix conversion, a search on Google finds [this](http://see-programming.blogspot.de/2013/02/infix-to-prefix-conversion.html)

Comment: The problem is to create the XML from the expression after